# How to convert json dynamic object to c# entity

Tags: json, model-view-controller, dynamic, entity, mapper

When I make mvc ajax json post applicaiton, there is a trouble to convert json dynamic object to entity.

In my app, movie is a business entity, json object has row status property than movie entity. When json data is posted to mvc server side, it can be converted to dynamic object, everyting is ok in this stage. But after handling some logic to each row status, it is needed to convert dynamic object to movie business entity, then begin database transaction logic. But there is a troulbe even I try different method to cast the object.

please did someone use the same cast method? thanks your advice or reply.

```
public class movie
{
    public int id
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public string title
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}



    /// <summary>
    /// Convert Json Object to Entity
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="id">ajax post value
    /// format: {"id": "{\"id\": 1, \"title\": \"sharlock\", \"RowStatus\": \"deleted\"}"}
    /// </param>
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [HttpPost]
    public void DoJsonSimple(string id)
    {
        string title;
        var entity = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(id);

        //*** entity is dynamic object
        //*** entity.id, entity.title and entity.RowStauts can be accessed.
        int first = entity.id;
        var status = entity.RowStatus;
        if (status == "deleted")
        {
            //*** m1 is null
            //*** m1.title can not be accessed
            movie m1 = entity as movie;
            title = m1.title;

            //*** m2 is an empty object
            //*** m2.id is 0, m2.title is null
            var m2 = AutoMapperHelper<dynamic, movie>.AutoConvertDynamic(entity);
            title = m2.title;

            //*** Exception: Object must implement IConvertible. 
            var m3 = EmitMapper.EMConvert.ChangeTypeGeneric<dynamic, movie>(entity);
            title = m3.title;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just create another class for the rows.

```cs
public class Request
{
    [JsonProperty("id")]
    public string Json { get; set; }
}

public class Movie
{
    [JsonProperty("id")]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("title")]
    public string Title { get; set; }
}

// either this for variant 1...
public class Row
{
    public string RowStatus { get; set; }
}

// or that for variant 2...
public class MovieRow : Movie
{
    public string RowStatus { get; set; }
}

[AllowAnonymous]
[HttpPost]
public void DoJsonSimple_Variant1(string id)
{
    var json = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Request>(id).Json;
    var entity = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MovieRow>(json);
    var row = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Row>(json);

    switch (row.RowStatus)
    {
        case "deleted":
            // delete entity
            break;

        // ...
    }

    // ...
}

[AllowAnonymous]
[HttpPost]
public void DoJsonSimple_Variant2(string id)
{
    var json = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Request>(id).Json;
    var row = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MovieRow>(json);
    var entity = (Movie)row;

    switch (row.RowStatus)
    {
        case "deleted":
            // delete entity
            break;

        // ...
    }

    // ...
}
```

Comment: hi, there are many entities in my project, if every entity needs to be created a new row class, it's heavy works...

Comment: That's why I suggested variant 1. You just need to deserialize your json two times with a different type. That's much less work than struggling with dynamic.

Comment: Yeah, it's better to new only one Row class, and deserialize json data twice for any entities. great ideas, Thanks.